# Use lambda expression to retrieve object array a field collection

Tags: c#, linq

```
public MyTest()
{
    MyClass a = new MyClass(13, "ab");
    MyClass b = new MyClass(24, "cd");
    List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
    myList.Add(a);
    myList.Add(b);
    //need help here
}

public class MyClass
{        
    public int fld1 { get; set; }
    public string fld2 { get; set; }

    public MyClass(int fld1, string fld2)
    {
        this.fld1 = fld1;
        this.fld2 = fld2;
    }
}
```

How can I use a lambda expression to get a collection of fld1 in `Mylist`? The expected result is a list with the value (13, 24). Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems are you having with your attempted solutions?

Comment: And why have you got two constructor for `MyTest` declared outside the class? Your code and question are entirely unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints, and bear in mind that if you ask a lot of questions which the community considers bad, you'll be automatically prevented from asking more questions.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The code is updated.

Comment: This is some pretty basic stuff. Any LINQ tutorial starts with `Select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic stuff,learn it please

```
List<int> result = myList.Select(x=>x.fld1).ToList();
```